# Find end line in .pdf

Tags: c++, pdf, plugins, acrobat-sdk

I'm developing a plugin for Adobe Acrobat X with C++ that copies all text from opened .pdf in a .txt file. I've tried text runs and text characters from PDEText, it copies all text but it concatenates all lines.

Q: how can I find where end line is in my text?

Comment: end line=where a paragraph ends and another one begins

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I made it!**

I parse the text letter by letter and I check if they're on the same row verifying top or bottom attribute from ASFixedRect ( I use PDETextGetBBox() to get ASFixedRect ).

Farewell!